# Should you add the value of non-significant effect when calculating effect of interaction term?

Tags: regression, interaction

I have a regression of the type

`y = Condition + Canadian + Condition*Canadian`,

where `Condition` is a dummy for whether a person has a certain medical condition and Canadian is a dummy for citizenship (Canadian or not)
Suppose the coefficients were

`y = 3Co + 0.5Ca + 4CoCa`.

`Co` and `CoCa` were significant, but `Ca` wasn't.

How do I calculate the effect for Canadians with this condition?

Is it `3 + 4 = 7` or is it `3 + 0.5 + 4 = 7.5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use your model for a prediction, ignore the parameter inference (p-values, confidence intervals) and just use the model. Your prediction is 7.5.

If you drop the Ca term, then you would fit the model on just Co and CoCa, which will result in different parameter estimates. It is usually suggested to include a variable on its own if it will be in an interaction, however.